# .htaccess wildcard redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wildcard

i have to redirect many urls

the structure is this:

OLD URL

```
/category/product-18-name.aspx
```

NEW URL

```
product18name.php (is merely an example)
```

i wish to do a regex, if a user type `/anyword/product-18-name.aspx` i wish that user will go to `product18name.php`

in short, i wish that the word in the middle of 2 first slashes, example: `/category/` that maybe a real category or any word to go to right page

so a user that type: `/helloworld/product-18-name.apsx` goes to `product18name.php`
or `/sdjfkskfdns/product-18-name.apsx` goes to `product18name.php`

Now my .htaccess is full of 301 redirects, like

```
Redirect 301 /electronic/peacemaker2_a5f89948-9f15-4606-9d5c-051d84a4c070.aspx http://www.site.com/product.php?id_product=23580
```

any help ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^.]+)\.aspx$ /$2$3$4.php
```

Of course, you're only asking for a 301 redirect, and that's all this does, redirects browser. If `product18name.php` isn't actually a php file, you'll just get a 404.